# Where is the "Edit build definition" permission in our TFS 2013 installation?

Tags: tfs

Our environment is a TFS 2013 server (12.0.21005.1 Tfs2013.RTM) which was upgraded from a fresh installation of TFS 2008, with a number of team projects and developers.

One thing that our developers regularly need to do is create and edit build definitions. According to both Visual Studio *and* all documentation I've been able to find, there should be a "Edit build definition" privilege (perhaps along with a few others) which controls access to this. But as you can see in the screenshot, **it doesn't exist in our installation:**

[image]

The only workaround I've found is to grant the people in question membership of the *Project Administrators* group, which is clearly not desirable. There is no group like *build administrators* or anything of the sort which might help, either; this is the list of groups available to choose from:

[image]

As a consequence, whenever a developer wants to edit a build definition (which is perfectly appropriate in our case) they keep running into:

[image]

**What, short of making everyone a project administrator in every team project they might possibly work in, can I do to resolve this?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's where to find the security settings for build definitions.

TFS 2015 UI: Go to the Build Explorer, click on the drop down arrow to the left of All build definitions or All XAML definitions.

[image]

VS Team Services and TFS "15" RC2 and newer: Go to Build and click on the Security button in the upper right side.

[image]

You will then get a dialog like the following with the build permissions.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The permissions that you show above are for Team Projects and not builds.

If you select a build and right-click on it you should get a permissions option. Here you will find build specific permission that you are looking for.

You can also set permissions through the API with PowerShell...

Comment: Even the *Contributors* group has "Edit build definition" set to *Inherited allow*. And am I supposed to go in there and change (or even verify) it for every single build definition created? (That's hundreds.) What about new builds? This seems to trace back to the project level, but I can't see any way to actually go there...

Comment: If the contributors group does not provide the permissions that you want you can change it. These are just the defaults..