# Unable to create TFS build definition (TF225000) and no Build Administrators group

Tags: tfs, build, upgrade

I am not able to create a build definition on my TFS 2013 team project as I get the error:

[image: TF225000: You do not have permission to create new build definitions]

I am in the Project Administrator group. I was added to the Project Collection Build Administrators group as a possible workaround but I still get the same error.

The team project has no “Build Administrators” group which is an obvious deficiency per [Project-level groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms252587(v=vs.120).aspx#project_level) in [Permission Reference for Team Foundation Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms252587(v=vs.120).aspx) from MSDN.

My environment is an on-prem TFS 2013 server that was recently upgraded from TFS 2010. The team project has no existing build definitions and has never used TFBuild before. The team project may have existed under an earlier version of TFS, that is unclear.

Q1: Any suggestion how to resolve this or further avenues of investigation?

My best guess is that the TFS admin will have to use the TFSSecurity tool to create the Build Administrators group and assign build-level permissions to it and the Project Administrators group. Probably the TFS admin should check the other team projects of the same vintage that were part of the TFS upgrade.

Q2: Also how and when permissions are assigned to “Build Definition Authors or Builders”, as shown in [Build-level permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms252587(v=vs.120).aspx#Build) from the same MSDN article?

I am not the TFS admin, just hoping to prime their work as they are overloaded.

My question may be related to [Where is the “Edit build definition” permission in our TFS 2013 installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396983/where-is-the-edit-build-definition-permission-in-our-tfs-2013-installation) but the symptoms are not all the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to have the appropriate permissions. First in visual studio go to your Builds tab and select "Actions | Security...".

[image]

After that you need to make sure that you have the correct permissions listed.

[image]

Simples...

Comment: Thanks that solved it for me. I didn't know about getting into the Build security permissions in the web portal. There were a few more steps in my case, I'll update my question with a few screen snaps to show that.

Comment: Is there a way to set these permissions at the collection level?

Comment: When you create a team project the default is set by the process template. These are Team Project level permissions.