# Cannot create new TFS build definitions

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I am testing out a new TFS 2015 instance and trying to set up a new build definition. The build agent is on a different server than TFS. I click the Create New Build Definition button from the TFS portal, select the Visual studio template and get this

[image: Empty Create New Build Definition Dialog]

What I would expect to see (which is working on our existing TFS server) is something like this

[image: Expected Create New Build Definition Dialog]

If I click create, the dialog closes but no build definition gets created. My only guesses as to what is causing this are it's either a permissions issue or some sort of installation/configuration issue. Any help resolving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you check whether you have enough [permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100204/unable-to-create-tfs-build-definition-tf225000-and-no-build-administrators-gro?rq=1) to create a build definition?

Comment: The issue turned out to be IIS related. Our servers disable certain HTTP verbs by default. I needed to get the DELETE and OPTIONS verbs added in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was related to IIS not having all HTTP verbs enabled (specifically DELETE and OPTIONS). Once these were added to the request filtering configuration, everything worked correctly.